# La pharmacie est à côté (de la - du -de ) cinema ?

Tags: expressions, expressions-idiomatiques, partitif

Quel est l'article partitif correct ?

- à côté de la cinéma
- à côté du cinéma
- à côté de cinéma.

Comment: Lequel diriez-vous?

Answer (score 2):

Dans le cas en question, il ne s'agit pas d'un article partitif mais d'une préposition suivie d'un article défini. (Crédit @jlliagre)

« Cinéma » est un mot masculin, donc on dit « à côté **du** cinéma. »

Par contre avec un mot féminin, on dirait :

> La pharmacie est à côté de la boulangerie.

Comment: Tu pourrais ajouter qu'il ne s'agit pas d'un article partitif mais d'une préposition suivie d'un article défini.

Comment: @jlliagre: Effectivement.